# Sharp architecture Membership

Tags: model-view-controller, membership, s#arp-architecture

Maybe this is a stupid question, but I dont know how to use Membership in sharp architecture template. I have seen how it is done in asp.net MVC (with AccountController, AccountView, and AccountModel / all of them autogenerated and binded to membeship provider).

I hope that my question is clear..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to implement your own membership provider and register in web.config, and then then have the required repository injected into your provider, or simply use the service locator to get the IRepository.

Mauricio Scheffer has written [a post about injected membership provider using windsor](http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2010/11/windsor-managed-membershipproviders.html) which should help you get started.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that there's nothing stopping you using the built in SqlMembershipProvider with S#arp Arch web sites. I've built a fair few websites using S#arp Arch and never had need to implement an SA-based membership provider - I just put an abstraction in front of the ASP.NET provider stuff so that my code is testable and take it from there.